# What's Integer in CosineSimilarity vector Map

Tags: vector

I'm going to use org.apache.commons.text.similarity.CosineSimilarity and im dos I look one method for use:

```
cosineSimilarity(Map<CharSequence,Integer> leftVector, Map<CharSequence,Integer> rightVector)
```

I need to compare two Strings, but I don't understand how I should to get Integer values for this.